# 2008 Genuine Buddy 125cc - Starting Problem

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starting

I bought Genuine Buddy yesterday on craigslist rode it home and of course it won't start this morning.  The battery works(the turning signals and hazard lights work), and the gas tank is full.  It barely wants to begin to turn over, sometimes, but mostly makes a clicking noise.

Edit:  I tried using the kickstarter to no avail as well

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Any suggestions would be truly helpful.one thing to note i tried using the kick starter to no avail as well

Answer (score 2):

A battery can run lights but not have enough energy to run a starter,

1. Check the battery connections, be sure they are clean and tight.
2. Check water levels in the battery, fill if needed, then put a 1amp charger on it for a few hours.
3. If you get it running again check the voltage at the battery while running with a DC voltmeter, it should be 13.5 volts or more at high idle, if not the charging system may not be working,

Those small batteries do not last long if not properly maintained (which most people do not), it may need a new battery.

Comment: one thing to note i tried using the kickstarter to no avail as well

Comment: Add that to your question please.

Answer (score 1):

It takes three things to make an engine go.  Spark, fuel and air.  So perhaps something controlling each of those three things isn't working well.  No way to guess here. Just start checking each of those.  If you are mechanically inclined, I'd start the search by troubleshooting [with the service manual.](http://www.modernbuddy.com/pdf/buddy125_service_manual.pdf) Page 13 of that manual is a very detail troubleshooting chart showing 27 repairs tied to  "hard starting or can't start".

Print out that page on paper, take your time and go through each of the root causes.  This is a great way to discover how things work, and the pride in fixing it yourself (Many of us have done this very thing... )

Is your vehicle fuel injected or does it have a carburetor?  I see from [the owner's manual for your scooter](http://www.modernbuddy.com/pdf/buddy_50_125_150_170-owners-2012.pdf) that both options have been produced.  Look at page 15 of that manual.  Is the Engine Management System (EMS) lamp present on your speedometer / cluster area?  If so, you've got a fuel injected model. If not, then you have a carburetor.

Is that light on?  If so, is it possible for you to get your hands on a code reader?

On other resource you might consider for this issue is http://www.modernbuddy.com/forum/   It's very possible the folks there may know quite a bit about your vehicle.

Good luck with it, stay safe.